# In Earth Engine, what can cause a "... is not a function" error?

Tags: google-earth-engine

When running my Earth Engine script, I receive an error message of the form:

```
[SOME METHOD] is not a function
```

What could be causing this, and how can I debug it?

For example:

```js
var collection = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
print(collection.get('title').length());
```

produces the error:

```
Line 2: image.get(...).length is not a function
```

Comment: What was the code snippet that you ran to see this error?

Answer (score 1):

The `X is not a function` error occurs when either:

1. a non-existent function/method is called on an Earth Engine object, or
2. a method is called on an Earth Engine object with an unknown type.

The general solution for the second case is to cast the object of unknown type with a constructor of the correct type.  Here are some specific examples of when this may occur, and how to fix it:

##### 1. When working with an element property returned by `.get()`

Earth Engine object properties can be of many different types (ex: `ee.String`, `ee.Number`, `ee.List`, etc.), so when calling a method on an object property that has not been casted to a specific data type, it is unclear whether a method exists.

For example:

```js
var collection = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
print(collection.get('title').length());
```

produces the error:

```
Line 2: image.get(...).length is not a function
```

The solution is to cast the object returned by `.get()` to a specific type. In this case we know the title property is of type `ee.String` and can explicitly cast it:

```js
print(ee.String(image.get('title')).length());
```

##### 2. In a function, calling a method on a function argument without casting first

For example, the following function has a parameter `tempKelvin` that has the method `subtract` applied to it:

```js
function KelvinToCelcius(tempKelvin) {
  return tempKelvin.subtract(-273.15);
}
print(KelvinToCelcius(300));`
```

This produces the error:

```
Line 2: tempKelvin.subtract is not a function
```

The solution is to cast the function parameters to their intended type.

```js
function KelvinToCelcius(tempKelvin) {
  tempKelvin = ee.Number(tempKelvin);
  return tempKelvin.subtract(273.15);
}
```

##### 3. When working with an object returned by `ee.FeatureCollection.first()`.

[ee.FeatureCollection.first()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-first) returns an abstract type of Element, which needs to be casted to a particular type of element.

For example:

```js
var collection = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
print(collection.first().area());
```

produces the error:

```
Line 2: collection.first(...).area is not a function
```

The solution is to cast the object returned by `.first()` to be an `ee.Feature`:

```js
print(ee.Feature(collection.first()).area());
```